# Setting up 4 containers with 4 IPs and 2 interfaces on EC2

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up 4 containers(with nginx) in a system with 4 IPs and 2 interfaces. Can someone please help me? For now only 3 containers are accessible. 4th one is timing out when tried to access from the browser instead of showing a welcome page. I have given the ip routes needed

Host is Ubuntu.

So when this happened I thought it had something to do with the ip routes. So in the same system I installed apache and created 4 virtual hosts each listening to different IPs and with different document routes.

When checked all the IPs were accessible and showed the correct documents.

### So now I am stuck, what do I do now!

### Configuration:

4 IPs and 2 interfaces. So I created 2 IP aliases. All IPs are configured by the /etc/network/interfaces except the first one. eth0 is is set to dhcp mode.

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 172.31.118.182
netmask 255.255.255.0


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 172.31.119.23
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1:1
iface eth1:1 inet static
address 172.31.119.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

It goes like this. The IPs are private IPs, so I guess there is no problem sharing it here.

```
eth0   - 172.31.118.249
eth0:1 - 172.31.118.182
eth1   - 172.31.119.23
eth1:1 - 172.31.119.11
```

Now the docker creation commands
All are just basic nginx containers, so when working it will show the default nginx page.

```
sudo docker create -i -t -p 172.31.118.249:80:80 --name web1 web_fresh
sudo docker create -i -t -p 172.31.118.182:80:80 --name web2 web_fresh
sudo docker create -i -t -p 172.31.119.23:80:80 --name web3 web_fresh
sudo docker create -i -t -p 172.31.119.11:80:80 --name web4 web_fresh
sudo docker start web1
sudo docker start web2
sudo docker start web3
sudo docker start web4
```

--

Now here web1 & web2 become immediately accessible. But the containers running on eth1 and eth1:1 are not. So I figured iproutes must be the issue and went ahead and added some routes.

```
ip route add 172.31.119.0/24 dev eth1 src 172.31.119.23 table eth1
ip route add default via 172.31.119.1 table eth1
ip route add 172.31.119.0/24 dev eth1 src 172.31.119.11 table eth11
ip route add default via 172.31.119.1 table eth11
ip rule add from 172.31.119.23 lookup eth1 prio 1002
ip rule add from 172.31.119.11 lookup eth11 prio 1003
```

This made web3 also accessible. But not the one from `eth1:1`. So here is where I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: Please share your configuration, so we can recreate the problem.  Is your Dockerfile published on github or the docker.io site?

Comment: Done adding the configuration. Thanks for trying to help me out. BTW the docker file I am trying is just a basic nginx container. You can try with apache as well.